# Unable to change Navigation containers based on a condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, redux-toolkit, asyncstorage

I am trying to switch navigators upon a condition of useToken exists or not. I am using asyncStorage To know if there's a token it's true and show app screens otherwise show authScreens.But I can't switch between Navigators whenever i hit login i am adding token to async storage if i hit logout i am removing token from asyncStorage.The Switching of containers not happening Instantly. It's happening on next reload or refresh . I am new to react native any resources related to this topic is appreciated. Thank you

```
       
App.js

const App = () => {
  const[userToken,setUserToken]=useState(null)
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getT=async()=>{
        const token=await getToken() //getting token from storage
        console.warn("auth",token)
        setUserLToken(token) //store token in local storage
     }
      getT()
    },[]
    )
    
    return(
      <NavigationContainer>
     {userToken === undefined ? <AuthStack/> : <AppStack/>}  
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
};


Appstack.js

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={TabNavigator}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Location" component={Location}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Calltoorder" component={Calltoorder}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Profile' component={Profile}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="EditProfile" component={EditProfile}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='ProductItem' component={ProductItem}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='SubCategories' component={SubCategories}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Categories' component={Categories}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='CartContainer' component={CartContainer} options={{ headerShown:true }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='MedicineCart' component={MedicineCart}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='LabCart' component={LabCart}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='OrderHistory' component={OrderHistory}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='ProductDescription' component={ProductDescription}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='Test' component={Test}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='DoctorCard' component={DoctorCard}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='DocBySpecialization' component={DocBySpecialization}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='DoctorDetails' component={DoctorDetails}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='AllTests' component={AllTests}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='AllPackages' component={AllPackages}/>      
      <Stack.Screen name='TestsAndPackagesById' component={TestsAndPackagesById}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='EmptyPage' component={EmptyPage} options={{ headerShown:true }}/>
      <Stack.Screen name='DiagSearch' component={DiagSearch}/>                                                            
      </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

authstack.js

const AuthStack = () => {
  return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Signin" component={Signin}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup}/>  
      <Stack.Screen name="ConfirmEmail" component={ConfirmEmail}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPass" component={ForgotPass}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="NewPass" component={NewPass}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please add AuthStack and AppStack code and how are you accessing the userToken  var share that code as well.

Comment: Added the appstack and authstack to the question, iam accessing usertoken on app.js page

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is using a "toggle flag" to re-run `useEffect` whenever some event occurs (in your case, it is token update).

In the below code, we give `tokenFlag` as a dependency to the `useEffect`. So whenever the `tokenFlag` state changes, useEffect will re-run. This will update your `userToken` and the Navigation containers will be changed.

```js
const App = () => {
  
  const[userToken,setUserToken] = useState(undefined)
  const[tokenFlag, toggleTokenFlag] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getT = async ()=>{
        const token=await getToken() //getting token from storage
        console.warn("auth",token)
        setUserLToken(token) //store token in local storage
    }
    getT()
  },[tokenFlag])
    
  const login = () => {
    // your login business logic...
    toggleTokenFlag(!tokenFlag)
  }

  const logout = () => {
    // your logout business logic...
    toggleTokenFlag(!tokenFlag)
  }

  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      {userToken === undefined ? <AuthStack/> : <AppStack/>}  
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};
```

If your login & logout functions are in different files, then you might have to use global state for triggering use effect.

Comment: If I use global state with redux , the state comes back to default stage. whenever the app closed and opened??

Comment: Yes, the state is always set to the initial state between application restarts. To save the state across application lifes use redux-persist.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this because of the empty array of dependencies in useEffect. An empty array means, the useEffect runs only once when the page is refreshed after the components are mounted. To run it after a change happens in token, Try adding your token variable to the dependency array

Comment: Tried to Add but 'Can't Find Variable token'

Comment: I think you have to add tokenFlag to the useEffect dependency array